# When I run this my code, it returns '[]'. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My first question in stackoverflow. I'm a beginner in python, and I want to request any instagram photo likes but my code return empty

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BsYt_megGfN/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
data = soup.findAll("div",{"class","Nm9Fw"})
print(data)
```

I want to see the names of people who like the photo but I didn't.

Comment: The empty list means that `soup.findAll` doesn't find any `div` with that `class` in the extracted html content.

Comment: The html parser for beautifulsoup can't parse the javascript.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, for scraping you should use a pre-compiled library like Anaconda. Download it here:https://www.anaconda.com/download/ and remember where the path to your python executable is.

You are returned with an empty list because instagram uses javascript. Requests isn't able to render the javascript into html for you, so you'll need use a more robust method, like selenium.

Try something like this:

## Install Selenium

In your terminal:

```
conda install selenium
```

## Download the Chromedriver

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

## Import Selenium into Your Code

```
import os  
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path-to-chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_options)  
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/BsYt_megGfN/")

html_source = driver.page_source  
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source,"html.parser")
data = soup.findAll("div",{"class","Nm9Fw"})
print(comments) # syntax for printing changes here for Python3
```

Run this with your Anaconda version of python.

Comment: Nitpick: Is there a particular reason OP has to use anaconda python? BS and selenium can both be installed in vanilla via pip just as easily as via conda, to my knowledge

Comment: I see that op is using python 2.7, and selenium is problematic with 2.7

Comment: @G.Anderson You're correct to be skeptical though. Due to the lack of native utf-8 support for many functions in Python 2.7, it can be difficult to troubleshoot scraping issues that happen as a result of unknown chars. Therefore, since op should use a different install, I figured the added stability of Anaconda would be helpful. Perhaps I am overreacting with conda?

Comment: Thanks for answer but as i said, im beginner in python. Can you more easily explain? I didn't quite get it. I downloaded anaconda and chromedriver but what i will do after?

Comment: @DanielScott that makes total sense, I wasn't aware of the utf-8 issue. I started on 3.6 and never looked back. Thanks for the explanation! I suppose another option if possible would be to upgrade to vanilla python 3 if anaconda is overkill, but it depends on OPs environment.

Comment: @G. Anderson Totally agree :)

Comment: @wizardhopper It takes a really long time to write out exhaustive tutorials. Is there a specific part you don't understand in my solution?

Comment: I used anaconda(spyder) before, this is okay. But why i downloaded chromedriver and what i will do this app, this is where i don't understand.

Comment: if I may, @wizardhopper the basic version is that the site uses asynchronous scripting to try to sstop people from doing exactly what you're trying to do with requests and beautiful soup. Selenium is a browser automation package that mimics an actual user on the site rather than just sending webrequests. In the solution posted above, a new chrome browser will open and find/click elements to get your data

Comment: @wizardhopper In the code snippet, insert the path to the chromedriver you downloaded. You downloaded it so that you can run the scraping in 'headless' mode (i.e. a browser window doesn't need to appear).

Comment: I'm getting error this line:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path-to-chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: What's the error? Please replace any pseudocode with real code.

Comment: I didn't understand, a very long error. Head of error:
 DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options

Comment: Post it in the question please